# Can I achieve begin insertion on a binary tree in O(log(N))?

Tags: algorithm

Consider a binary tree and some traverse criterion that defines an ordering of the tree's elements.

Does it exists some particular traverse criterion that would allow a `begin_insert` operation, i.e. the operation of adding a new element that would be at position 1 according to the ordering induced by the traverse criterion, with O(log(N)) cost?

I don't have any strict requirement, like the tree guaranteed to be balanced.

EDIT: 
But I cannot accept lack of balance if that allows degeneration to O(N) in worst case scenarios.

EXAMPLE:

Let's try to see if in-order traversal would work.

Consider the BT (not a binary search tree)

```
                      6
                   /     \
                  13      5
                 /  \    /
                2    8  9
```

In-order traversal gives 2-13-8-6-9-5

Perform `begin_insert(7)` in such a way that in-order traversal gives 7-2-13-8-6-9-5:

```
                      6
                   /     \
                  13      5
                 /  \    /
                2    8  9
               /
              7
```

Now, I think this is not a legitimate `O(log(N))` strategy, because if I keep adding values in this way the cost degenerates into `O(N)` as the tree becomes increasingly unbalanced

```
                      6
                   /     \
                  13      5
                 /  \    /
                2    8  9
               /
              7
             /
            *
           /
          *
         /
```

This strategy would work if I rebalance the tree by preserving ordering:

```
                      8
                   /     \
                  2       9
                 /  \    / \
                7    13 6   5
```

but this costs at least O(N).

According to this example my conclusion would be that in-order traversal does not solve the problem, but since I received feedback that it should work maybe I am missing something?

Comment: in-order traversal? you can even achieve the begin insertion in O(1).

Comment: @svs I don't see how to avoid O(N) nodes swaps using in-order traversal... unless you make the tree awfully unbalanced.. or I am missing something?

Comment: `O(N) nodes swaps` what do you mean?

Comment: Balanced trees were specifically designed to guarantee log n operations; why would balancing a tree make it worse?

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon But you said the tree doesn't need to be balanced. All you'd need to do is add a new root node.

Comment: I think it would be better if you give us some context. I believe that you are overengineering at the moment.

Comment: position 1 in-/post- or preorder? you should be a bit more specific about this.  Doesn't make a difference though, since all are atleast O(log n) or even faster

Comment: hmmm... just let me think about it

Comment: Thanks for feedback, please see improved question

Comment: So basically you want to be sure that if you call `begin_insert` the you wouldn't unbalance the tree (you keep saying that you allow unbalancing but you can't allow degenerate path with length `n`. well that's exactly why balancing is necessary to make sure path `n` never happens). why do you at all need `begin_insert` in first place? can't you use just simple `insert`. Seems like you want to know where exactly you'd insert the element. In that case you can insert it find the parent and remove it - you have found where you'd insert it.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need this kind of operations in first place

Comment: @svs This is just a self-crafted exercise. I am trying to see if there exists a particular traverse ordering that would make balancing unnecessary for a `begin_insert` operation. As a further example, breadth-first traverse would achieve this for `end_insert` operation, insertion would be `log(N)` and the balance is automatically preserved. For `begin_insert` it seems to be much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting, deleting and finding in a binary tree all rely on the same search algorithm to find the right position to do the operation. The complexity of this O(max height of the tree). The reason is that to find the right location you start at the root node and compare keys to decide if you should go into the left subtree or the right subtree and you do this until you find the right location. The worst case is when you have to travel down the longest chain which is also the definition for height of the tree.

If you don't have any constraints and allow any tree then this is going to be O(N) since you allow a tree with only left children (for example).

If you want to get better guarantees you must use algorithms that promise that the height of the tree has a lower bound. For example [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) guarantees that your tree is balanced so the max height is always log N and all the operations above run in O(log N). [Red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) don't guarantee log N but promise that the tree is not going to be too unbalanced (min height * 2 >= max height) so it keeps O(log N) complexity (see page for details).

Depending on your usage patterns you might be able to find more specialized data structures that give even better complexity (see [Fibonacci heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap)).